# How to write a method that works for all numbers

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-method

I'm writing a `Fixnum` class method `to_words` that takes any number and translates it to English so,

```
2.to_words
#=> "two"
2030.to_words
#=> "two thousand thirty"
```

I would like it to handle all numbers, and there a problem once I get a little past 1 billion:

```
1000002000.to_words
#=> "one billion two thousand"
1074000000.to_words
#=> NoMethodError
1074000000.class
#=> Bignum
```

Is there a way to extend my `Fixnum.to_words` method to `Bignum`?

Comment: `1074000000` is a `Fixnum` actually and faaaaaar away from `Bignum`s

Comment: not true on ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `Fixnum` and `Bignum` inherit from `Integer`, so it would be preferable in your case to define `#to_words` on `Integer` so either `Fixnum`s or `Bignum`s would inherit that method.

Comment: This is the right solution. Ruby provides a very nice inheritance hierarchy for the numerical types for this exact reason.